# How to format Standard ML print output?

Tags: formatting, string-formatting, sml

I am trying to format some output in Standard ML.  I need to display some real values as rounded to a certain decimal place, and I also need to be able to display some real values using scientific notation.

The signature for the print function is

```
val it = fn : string -> unit
```

which doesn't seem to allow for the use of formatting codes or any other parameters.  I also haven't had any luck finding documentation online.  Ideally I was hoping the print function in SML would have similar functionality to printf in C...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard ML is a statically-typed language. It's hard to make something like `printf` in a type-safe way.

The SML Basis Library contains some formatting operations for numbers. But to use them is relatively verbose and relatively difficult to figure out. For example, to format a real number into a string in scientific notation with 3 places after the decimal point, you can do something like this:

```
Real.fmt (StringCvt.SCI (SOME 3)) 4324423423.5; (* evaluates to string "4.324E9" *)
```

Ugly, right?

Some implementations offer other formatting methods. For example, SML/NJ has a `Format` structure that allows you to use a `printf`-style formatting string. However, the arguments must be wrapped according to their type:

```
Format.format "%.3e" [Format.REAL 4324423423.5]; (* evaluates to string "4.324e09" *)
```

Other SML implementations might have their own custom formatting functions.